# How GET a search result of DIR filename.css /b /s and use in the following CMD command?

Tags: string, search, cmd, get, macros

Trying to write a basic macro

```
:: go to install folder
CD %USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Vivaldi\Application

:: take a search
DIR common.css /b /s
```

then I get the result

```
C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Vivaldi\Application\1.13.1008.14\resources\vivaldi\style\common.css
```

and now I must to `CD` to this path without hands =)

---

ok, I done something already

```
:: make a filepath 
DIR %USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Vivaldi\Application\*common.css /s /b > %USERPROFILE%\Desktop\filepath.txt
:: placing the first line of a file into a variable
SET /P _path=<filepath.txt
```

but after I need to go for it to make a changes

```
TYPE C:\\vs\AppendThis.txt >> (paste _path here) common.css
```

---

just put my variable inside %_path% and it works!!! =0